# How can i find and get the value of a match with regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following pattern `>4.66<` I would like to find in a string. The following code is ment to find the pattern and give med the double value:

```
            string data = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

            string pattern = "^>\\d.\\d<";

            if (Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern))
            {
                MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(data, pattern);

                foreach (Match m in mc)
                {
                    double value = double.Parse(m.Value.Substring(1, m.Value.Length - 1));
                    string foo = "" + 2;
                }
            }
```

I think my pattern is wrong since i cant seem to find >4.66< and I see in the source that it is right there :D

Comment: Change it to: `string pattern = @">\d\.\d+<";`

Comment: the dot in your pattern defines any character that will match. Use \. Also you put a ^ in front of your pattern which means he will search at the beginning of your text only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
(?<=>)\d+\.\d+(?=<)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Slightly simplified code:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(data, @"(?<=>)\d+\.\d+(?=<)");
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    double value = double.Parse(m.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

You don't need to call `IsMatch` method, because `Matches` will simply return you empty collection if nothing is matched.

Answer (score 1):

1. Main thing is, you are missing a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). With `\d` you are matching exactly 1 digit. If you want to match more of them, you need to define it.

   `+` is a quantifier repeating the previous item 1 ore more.
2. To match a dot literally it needs to be escaped, because it [is a special character in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html).
3. Use a verbatim string to avoid double escaping
4. Match only what you need ([like Ulugbek described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23782255/626273)) with [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) or use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
5. I removed `^` from your pattern, because this is matching the start of the string, and you wrote you want to find within a string.

So we end up with:

```
string pattern = @">(\d.\d+)<";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(data, pattern);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    double value = double.Parse(m.groups[1]);
}
```